# How to announce IP address in BGP on Cisco router?

Tags: cisco, bgp

I have a BGP router which announces my networks, but I need announce its IP address in BGP. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found, I've create an loopback interface and add it with network command into my bgp announce.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 1):

Normally your upstream ISP will configure a /30 link to you from their address space.  You form a EBGP peer with their router over this /30 link.  Then any BGP announcements you make to that ISP have a next-hop of your end of the /30 point to point.

Your upstream ISPr selling you BGP should really help walk you through this.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "Cisco bgp configuration" returns this document
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_configuration_example09186a008009456d.shtml

Probably is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

It is not sensible to announce a single IP address via BGP - upstream routers will filter any range smaller than /25, and hence the address will not be routable.